# Generating Random Vectors with Arbitrary Marginal Distributions via NORTA

Tags: correlation, random-generation, marginal-distribution, copula

When generating random variates from different marginal distributions using the NORTA (Normal-to-Anything) method, as described in [Cario & Nelson 2007](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.48.281&rep=rep1&type=pdf), why is $\varrho$ required?

> To adjust this correlation, we can restrict attention to adjusting $\ E[X_iX_j]$, since
>
> $$ Corr[X_i; X_j ] = \frac{E[X_iX_j]-E[X_i]E[X_j]}{\sqrt{Var[X_i]Var[X_j]}} $$
>
> and $\ E[X_i]$, $\ E[X_i]$, $\ Var[X_i]$ and $\ Var[X_i]$ are fixed by $\ F_{X_i} $ and $\ F_{X_j} $. Then, since $\ (Z_i, Z_j)$ has a standard bivariate normal distribution with correlation $\ Corr[Z_i; Z_j ] = (Z_i, Z_j)$, we have
>
> $$ E[X_iX_j] = E \Bigl\{ F^{-1}_{X_i}[\Phi(Z_i)]F^{-1}_{X_j}[\Phi(Z_j)] \Bigl\} $$
>   $$  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F^{-1}_{X_i}[\Phi(Z_i)]F^{-1}_{X_j}[\Phi(Z_j)]\varphi_{\varrho z(i,j)}(z_i,z_j)dz_idz_j $$
>
> where $\ \varphi_{\varrho z(i,j)}(z_i,z_j) $ is the standard bivariate normal probability density function (pdf) with correlation $\ \varrho z(i,j) $. **We are only interested in distributions for which this expectation exists**

Isn't it possible to create the desired variates by feeding the required parameters straight into a Gaussian copula? For instance, a -0.5 correlation with U(10) and Expo(10). MATLAB example below.

```
corrZ = [1 -0.5;-0.5 1];
size = 200;
Z = mvnrnd([0 0], corrZ, size); 
X(:,1) = expinv( normcdf(Z(:,1)), 10); 
X(:,2) = unidinv(normcdf(Z(:,2)), 10); 
X
mean(X)
scatter(X(:,2),X(:,1))
```

Does $\varrho$ preserve the variances and means of the marginals? What am I misunderstanding?

One other question: what does it mean when the value found for $\varrho$ lies outside (-1,1)? I have some marginals that make the root finding for the $\varrho$ unsolvable. Why does this occur?

Comment: What do you mean by "the value found for $\rho$"?  You haven't given any method or equations to determine it.  If you believe it's the correlation of $X$, then run your code with a value of $-0.99$ and compute the actual correlations that arise in samples.